# Convert html to image with pagination using C#

Tags: c#, pagination, webbrowser-control, gdi+

I'm working on a windows service in c# 4.0 wich transform different file in image (tif and jpeg)

I have a problem when i want to convert a html file (usually an e-mail) in image.

I use WebBrowser

```
var browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.DocumentCompleted += this.BrowserDocumentCompleted;
browser.DocumentText = html;
```

and DrawToBitmap

```
var browser = sender as WebBrowser;
Rectangle body = new Rectangle(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.X * scaleFactor,
    browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Y * scaleFactor,
    browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width * scaleFactor,
    browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height * scaleFactor);

browser.Height = body.Height;
Bitmap output = new Bitmap(body.Width, body.Height);
browser.DrawToBitmap(output, body);
```

It works fine for small or medium html, but with long html (like 22 000 height px or more)
I have GDI exeptions on DrawToBitmap :

- Invalid parameter
- Not an image GDI+ valid

According to internet, this kind of error append because the image is too big.

My question : How can i convert html in X images (pagination) without generate the big image and crop after, and if it's possible without using library.

Thank you in advance.

Edit : I found a tricky solution : surround the html with a div witch gonna set the page and another for the offset, for exemple :

```
<div style="height:3000px; overflow:hidden"> 
<div style="margin-top:-3000px">
```

But this solution can crop on a line of text or in the middle of an image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your anwser Noseratio.

I founded a solution by using printing and a virtual printer to get image file.

Save the html in a file and remove all encoding :

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "<meta[^>]*http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"[^>]*>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);
using (var f = File.Create(filePath))
{
   var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
   f.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Run the print without show the webbrowser and printing popup :

```
const short PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2;
const int OLECMDID_PRINT = 6;
const int OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2;

dynamic ie = browser.ActiveXInstance;
ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION);
```

I use PDFCreator for virtual printing and it keep me all files in a folder. It's not easy to get all of this file (know when printing is finish, how many files and when you can use them...) but it isn't the purpose of this post!

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a custom [IE Print Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use [DEVICERECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969428(v=vs.85).aspx) and [LAYOUTRECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969430(v=vs.85).aspx) elements to drive the pagination. The lines wouldn't get cut in the middle then, and you'd capture a bitmap of each `DEVICERECT` as a page. You'd need to issue  `CGID_MSHTML`/[IDM_SETPRINTTEMPLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command to MSHTML document object (`webBrowser.Document.DomDocument as IOleCommandTarget`) to enable the Print Template-specific element tags like those. More information about Print Templates can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19172580/1768303).

**[EDITED]** You can even use [IHTMLElementRender::DrawToDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API on a `DEVICERECT` object to draw its content on a bitmap DC. You'd need to enable `FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI` and disable `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING` [feature control settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your `WebBrowser` hosting app to use `IHTMLElementRender::DrawToDC`.