# WebBrowser print settings

Tags: c#, .net, printing, webbrowser-control

How ca i change my html document orientation(to Landscape) for printing using WebBrowser control.

```
var browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var ws = sender as WebBrowser;
        //change paper size and orientation
        ws.Print();
    };
browser.Navigate(path);
```

I need to change paper size format to C5 and orientation to Landscape before printing.
How can i do this without any dialogs?

Comment: Which WebBrowser control? WPF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To control HTML printing layout beyond [@media CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) with `WebBrowser` (both WinForms and WPF), you would need to implement your own [Internet Explorer Print Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That would provide full control over headers, margins, columns, etc.

Specifically, you're after [TemplatePrinter.orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It isn't properly documented, but it works. The source of the standard IE print template can be viewed when navigated to `res://ieframe.dll/preview.dlg`.

Some other relevant resources:

- [Beyond Print Preview: Print Customization for Internet Explorer 5.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250434%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Print Preview 2: The Continuing Adventures of Internet Explorer 5.5 Print Customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Print Templates, Part I](http://www.webreference.com/js/column89/index.html)
- [View templates for HTML source documents](http://www.google.com/patents/US7647553)
- [Demystifying printing with the Microsoft WebBrowser control and ShowHTMLDialogEx](http://marc.durdin.net/2011/07/demystifying-printing-with-the-microsoft-webbrowser-control-and-showhtmldialogex-2/)
- [Add support to print & preview HTML in a dialog-based MFC app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18926793/1768303)
- [IDM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [IDM_PRINTPREVIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSKB: How to print custom headers and footers for a WebBrowser control in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267240)

Comment: Thanks for this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/267240 You seem to know quite a lot about printing from IE. So do you know -- that link actually contradicts this one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/236777 that basically says that there's no way to change footer/header in IE programmatically. So I'm curious, since the first page clearly shows how to do it, is there a way to also: A) Change page margins, and B) Specify printer when using `OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER`?

Comment: @c00000fd, A and B are possible not so straightforward. You'd need to roll put your own print template - check the other links, particularly [this](http://marc.durdin.net/2011/07/demystifying-printing-with-the-microsoft-webbrowser-control-and-showhtmldialogex-2).

Comment: Oh, man, Delphi. People still use it? Any C/C++ (or at least C#) links in your arsenal? I'm basically looking to allow printing from `WebControl` to allow print customization from within the program (w/o user interface from IE.) And that stuff is so undocumented...

Comment: I don't have any C++ code I could post here. To an extent, this stuff *is* documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753358(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The printer settings are stored at registry, so you can edit it as a default value for all global printing. https://www.scriptinghouse.com/2022/05/the-hidden-settings-of-internet-explorer-page-margin-fonts-default-page.html