# Closing form after printing a web browser control contained in it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

I'm taking some random print through the html and web browser control in vb.net winforms
Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myWebBrowser As New WebBrowser
    AddHandler myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleted
    myWebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.bing.com")

  End Sub

  Private Sub DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    With DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
      If .ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        .Print()
      End If
    End With
  End Sub

End Class
```

I want the form to be closed after the print. Now if I write `Me.Close()` after `.Print()`  nothing is being printed. what should I do to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

**::Update::**

after @Noseratio's suggestion I tried to handle the event `onafterprint` in my html and tried to invoke `Me.Close()` using `ObjectFoprScripting` set to my form. But that is firing the close method without any print.

**Here is my code**

> script tag in my html page

```
<script>
    function window.onafterprint() {
        window.external.Test('called from script code');
    }
</script>
```

> VB.net Code of my form

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security.Permissions

<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = False
        WebBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
        WebBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = False
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText("localprint.htm")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test(ByVal message As String)
        MessageBox.Show(message, "client code")
        Me.BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Sub() Me.Close(), MethodInvoker))
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        WebBrowser1.Print()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Handle [`onafterprint` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms536788(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: No problem. FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19172580/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio:: Wow, you just solved my next few quires even before posting. :D Thank a ton for the resource

Comment: Krishanu, glad it helped. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/1768303) might also be of your interest; I have a bunch of other `WebBrowser`-related posts.

Comment: [Here are them all](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1768303+%5Bwebbrowser-control%5D) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Found my solution***

No need to handle `onafterprint` in javascript.
Here is what I did,

**Step 1**
Added a reference to `SHDocVw.dll` in my project. This can be found in `c:\windows\system32` folder.

**Step2**

> My new updated code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security.Permissions

<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = False
        WebBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
        WebBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = False
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText("localprint.htm")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim wb As WebBrowser = TryCast(sender, WebBrowser)

        Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer = DirectCast(wb.ActiveXInstance, SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
        AddHandler ie.PrintTemplateInstantiation, AddressOf IE_OnPrintTemplateInstantiation
        AddHandler ie.PrintTemplateTeardown, AddressOf IE_OnPrintTemplateTeardown

        'Just to get reference of  the webBrowser1 control in ie events, uncomment the below line
        'ie.PutProperty("WebBrowserControl", DirectCast(wb, Object))

        wb.Print()
    End Sub

    Private Sub IE_OnPrintTemplateInstantiation(pDisp As Object)
        ' The PrintTemplateInstantiation event is fired when the print job is starting.
    End Sub

    Private Sub IE_OnPrintTemplateTeardown(pDisp As Object)
        ' The PrintTemplateTeardown event is fired when the print job is done.

        'Just to get reference of  the webBrowser1 control, uncomment the below line
        'Dim iwb2 As SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 = TryCast(pDisp, SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)
        'Dim wb As WebBrowser = DirectCast(iwb2.GetProperty("WebBrowserControl"), WebBrowser)

        Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```