# How do I programatically change printer settings with the WebBrowser control by using c++?

Tags: c++, printing, iwebbrowser2

I use IWebBrowser2 in my simple win32-application. I want programatically get and set printer settings like page size or page orientation.

I have found a lot of examples with using C# or VB, but no one for C++.

Perfect variant would be with using some COM-interface.

Comment: This post might help you -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132365/Configuring-Printer-Settings-Programmatically

Comment: Are you using CLR C++ (ie NET C++) or do you prefere basic WinAPI functions?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Basic WinAPI functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebBrowser print settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098571/webbrowser-print-settings)

Comment: No, it's a question with other language.

Answer (score 2):

As you speak of COM-interface, I assume that you do not want NET functions but [winAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ones.

Here is a first glance view of referenced page:

- `EnumPrinters` allows to get the list of printers - unsure whether you need it...
- `OpenPrinter` give you a handle to a specific printer

  ```
  BOOL OpenPrinter(
    LPTSTR pPrinterName,         // printer or server name
    LPHANDLE phPrinter,          // printer or server handle
    LPPRINTER_DEFAULTS pDefault  // printer defaults
  );
  ```
- `GetPrinter` gives you many information on a printer, and specifically the `PRINTER_INFO_9` structure specifying the per-user default printer settings.

  ```
  BOOL GetPrinter(
    HANDLE hPrinter,    // handle to printer
    DWORD Level,        // information level (9 to get the PRINTER_INFO_9)
    LPBYTE pPrinter,    // printer information buffer
    DWORD cbBuf,        // size of buffer
    LPDWORD pcbNeeded   // bytes received or required
  );
  typedef struct _PRINTER_INFO_9 {
    LPDEVMODE pDevMode;   // contains actual setting like orientation...
  } PRINTER_INFO_9, *PPRINTER_INFO_9;
  ```
- `SetPrinter` allows to set configuration back to printer

  ```
  BOOL SetPrinter(
    HANDLE hPrinter,  // handle to printer object
    DWORD Level,      // information level (9 to use the PRINTER_INFO_9)
    LPBYTE pPrinter,  // printer data buffer
    DWORD Command     // printer-state command
  );
  ```

You can then use the `StartDoc`, `EndDoc` calls to do actual printing enclosing each page with `StartPage` `EndPage`, optionnaly regestering an `AbortProc` procedure. Alternatively, you I think that you can use the configured printer through `IWebBrowser2` interface but I never used that part.

I know that this is still far for a real example of configuring a printer and using it, but at least it should give enough hints and pointers.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. Unfortunately, I have a problem with EnumPrinters, because it returns only "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". And GetPrinter for this returns empty structure. I'll try to solve this. Another one point, at msdn written that PRINTER_INFO_9 is a level for default(!) user settings. Do you know, will some changes in UI affect on return of GetPrinter?